# How should I reject "minor" edits like this?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Now that the "too minor" reason is gone, I was wondering how should I properly reject minor edits like the follows:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5805313

Original:

> I wonder if someone would be so kind as to tell me why my code is not
>   working. I want my random generator to choose between question 1 or
>   question 2 and then execute the relevant IF While. As a newbie, I'm
>   struggling. The full code is shown:

After change:

> ... then execute the relevant (IF While)[italicized]. As a newbie, I'm
>   struggling. The (full code)[bold-faced] is  ...

I don't think the edit add any value to the OP. Nor is it vandalism, invalid, radical or plagiarism. What's the proper way to prevent this edit from being committed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5805313):

[image: Reject and Edit: This edit did not correct critical issues with the post]

Also, for questions like this, I recommend dropping out of review and voting to close. Note that [there's a suggestion on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected/239100#239100) for adding a reason specifically for edits to doomed posts that don't, uh, un-doom them - don't hesitate to upvote that or drop in your own suggestions on that thread.

Comment: *"adding a reason specifically for edits to doomed posts"* - +1... Sometimes my comment on an edit includes "why am I doing this for a question that's going to be closed...".